# jump hover to next a element

Tags: jquery, css, hover

how can I make a jquery auto-mousehover after 3 second on a elements in a div: 
like:

```
<div class="myClass="><a href="demo1">text</a></div>

<div class="myClass="><a href="demo2">text</a></div>

<div class="myClass="><a href="demo3">text</a></div>
```

first demo1 after 3 seconds mouseover jump to demo2 and then to demo3 - after loop.

thank you!

AD

Comment: You mean move the mouse pointer position? If yes, there's no way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need mouse hover like, highlighter?  If yes, verify below link.

use setinterval function . check this link, http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/77/

[http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/77/][1]

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/77/
```

Comment: what about not changing the whole html? http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/78/

Comment: @DavidFregoli - Ya fine, but, still not clear whether he[ad2003] needs this kind of hover or he expecting some other.

Comment: hi guys! Exactly. It's a highlighter. Sorry, that I was not clear in my question.

Comment: @ad2003 : fine, Is this solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use the `:hover` css pseudo class there it is not possible.

A possible solution to this is to add a class like `active` to the element and style it using the class

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".current-menu-item a").mouseover();
});
```

try this